# How does Kindle's Android application handle the clicks for dictionary lookup

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

In the Kindle app for Android, there is a feature where you can long-click on a word in the book, and a menu will show up where you can choose Dictionary, and look up that word.

I am wondering how one would go about capturing those word clicks?

I was thinking of a ClickableSpan but that would capture all clicks, not just long-clicks.

Can anyone point me to some code samples, or suggest a strategy?

Many thanks
Victor

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that they are using a [GestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) of some sort as the onTouchListener for the View. After the listener is set, they simply handle the longPress events.

Comment: Hmm, but then how do they detect the word that was clicked?

Comment: Likely, what they do is take the x, y coordinates from the MotionEvent from the onTouch(), then check to see if that x, y hit the word in their view.

Comment: I don't know how Kindle handles it internally. Ultimately they do some sort of hit test, where they have a rect for a word and they check to see if the x, y from the touch lands inside the word rect. How they get the rect is an implementation detail specific to the Kindle app.

Comment: What if every word is assigned to a button and then they simply handled the long click events from there? Might be a rather memory-expensive application though.